# Drupal 7 custom node add form with Field Collections

Tags: forms, drupal, field, addition

I have a content type with a number of Field Collection fields.

The design for this form is relatively complex and cannot simply be styled with CSS. I want to output the form in a template, so each individual field can be styled.

I spent 6 hours last night looking for a solution to this. I've seen custom modules, hook_form_alter and various methods that might use Display Suite or other modules. None have worked for me so far.

My goal is to simply output the form fields (including Field Collection fields) in a template for styling. Has anybody achieved this?

Comment: Did you saw/tried Panels? It has layout mode for node adding

Comment: I don't want to use a module - I want the fields to be available in a template through code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by creating an override template for the node add/edit page.

You will first need to add a new template suggestion for node forms. The first section of this page shows you how to do this:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122

After that, you should be able to print individual form elements into the new template. For example:

```
<div class="column-left">
  <?php print drupal_render($form['first_name']); ?>
  <?php print drupal_render($form['last_name']); ?>
</div>
<div class="column-right">
  <?php print drupal_render($form['email']); ?>
  <?php print drupal_render($form['phone']); ?>
</div>
```